# Kibana Alerts aknowlidge-store-delete

Tags: kibana, wazuh

Could you please help me with alerts in Kibana coming from Wazuh as FIM?
I am successfully getting alerts from wazuh agents and showing it in Agent events.

But I am able only to check the alert. There is no button to aknowledge or delete seen alert.
As I am new in wazuh monitoring, could you please let me know, how can I store or set aletrs as completed?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the alerts are indexed and you can't remove them(you can remove the index). The alerts' purpose is not to be deleted, the alerts allow you to have an "activity history". I think it is good to have all the alerts during the time, even if you have solved or checked that alert.

Comment: Thank you for your responde. I want to use Wazuh as file monitoring. I need to create snapshot of folders and than every day run audit monitoring. If there is something chenged and different as snapshot, wazuh send alert. I will check that alert and solve, why and how was file changed. 
So there cant be checked alerts send to the ,,completed,, or some other group? Any idea please?

Comment: If you want to use Wazuh as a file monitoring tool take a look at the [FIM](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/capabilities/file-integrity/index.html) module. It monitors modifications by comparing the new files’ checksums to the old checksums verifying the integrity of the files. In the `How it works` section, you have a brief about this module. Hope it helps you!